# Creating and addressing array NASM

Tags: arrays, assembly, nasm, x86-16

I just made a snake game in assembly 8086 and tried to compile it with NASM. I discovered that I must "fit" my program. First, I'll be glad if someone can extract all the NASM's adaptations. Second, the terminal gives me the next message:"comma, colon or end of line expected".
The data segment

```
BOARDARR: TIMES 1896 DB 0
```

The code segment

```
mov bx, 3d7h
mov BOARDARR[BX], 1
```

Can someone please help me? thanks.

Comment: On what line does the assembler give you that error message?

Comment: The mov boardarr[bx], 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`comma, colon or end of line expected` in this case is caused by an improper syntax of the code itself, namely `mov BOARDARR[BX], 1`. In NASM, all memory references need to be made in brackets, in which the effective address of the operand is calculated. Therefore, what you want is (I assume) `mov [BOARDARR+BX], 1`, which will cause a `1` to be written to the address `BOARDARR + 3d7h`.

However, doing only that correction will cause another error related to the operand size not being specified. Since [NASM doesn't care about variable types](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.10.09/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.3), it doesn't care that you `BOARDARR` was declared with a `db` and treats it as an ordinary, un-typed chunk of memory, not an array of byte-sized elements.

In order to remedy this, you need to explicitly state the size of the operand that you want to write to the specified address, since - even in real mode, which I assume that you're using - `MOV` with a memory operand has two flavors : byte-sized and word-sized. In this case, you have two options to write that instruction :

1. `mov [BOARDARR+BX], byte 1`, which will cause `01` to be written to `BOARDARR+BX`, or
2. `mov [BOARDARR+BX], word 1`, which will cause `01 00` (in that particular order, since x86 is Little Endian) to be written to `BOARDARR+BX`.

Hope this clears things up.